# Prometheus metric relabel for value

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

Basically I want to relabel the metric value , path = /api/v2/users/-/hashes/004fc134-93ba-4c48-b0da-e114f2245b77/activate

to

/api/v2/users/externalhashes/ops

I tried this below but its not working.
Am i missing something?

> 

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [path]
    regex: (\/api\/v2\/users\/+.\/hashes\/[0-9a-z\-]{1,40}\/\w.*)
    replacement: ‘/api/v2/users/externalhashes/ops’
    target_label: path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
regex: '/api/v2/users/.+/hashes/[0-9a-z\-]{1,40}/\w.*'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcelo

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus uses Golang `re2` package to parse Regular expressions
https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Googling quickly for a tester I found this
https://regoio.herokuapp.com/

Marcelo's answer does the work :+1:

Comment: Thanks for clarifying